# Design considerations for uploading documents into MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, configuration, user-controls, design

I am working on a design document for one of my projects in MOSS 2007. There is a requirement to create a custom interface to upload document along with metadata to a document library. I am not sure which one will be the best approach for this:

- creating a webpart and deploying on the webpart page or
- creating a custom aspx page and deploying it or
- creating a user control and using it on the page.
- or if there is any better way to do this, please suggest.

I would appreciate if I could have the pros and cons of the above mentioned approaches.

Thanks,
Somya

Answer (score 1):

1) The web part will require to be registered as a safe control, a user control is an automatically registered version since no options can be set at run time. If you are using visual studio or the equivalent -local on deployment this is never a concern.

2) Not required, you may want to do this to remove the web part security concerns however for this project creating a web part / user control would save time as you will find yourself writing much more code.

3) Probably the easiest solution as a user control is registered as safe automatically (Only server controls require registration into the web.config) you don't really want a user to add a new instance or modify it at all so this is perhaps the best route, easiest deployment, easiest to code and shortest all round implementation.

Comment: Hey Hugh, Thanks for the valuable input. In case I opt for user control, this user control will have code behind which again needs to be complied as DLL and there will be a safe control entry required for it. Also will this page be unghosted if I use user control in it? Thanks, Somya